# Context-aware regular expression

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have a long Latex document and have been requested to change every appearance of the math symbol upper case A with lower case a.

The only problem is that this symbol is repeated so many times (I guess over 300) within latex math expressions. It also occurs more than once in a single expression.

I guess that fixing this manually requires a considerable effort, let alone that I will definitely overlook many of the replacements. Also, note that the normal "Find/replace" function of standard editors is out of question here, because the letter A (not the math symbol A) occurs almost everywhere in the document.

So I think a regular expression is a good candidate to solve my problem; however, I need to make sure that I do it right, and this is the main reason for this post. I appreciate if someone can take a look at the regex below and tell me what can go wrong and how to fix it.

As a start, I need to list the places I want to fix with grep, so I wrote:

```
$ # list all the occurrences of "A" inside latex math environment
$ # i.e., surrounded by $ $ 
$ # Note that since $ is a special char in regex, we have to escape it
$ grep -n '\$[^\$]*A[^\$]*\$' doc.tex
```

This grep works as expected, but not as I want. To illustrate the issue, consider the following simple example:

```
$ cat -n test.tex 
     1  Abc $y_1=A x$. 
     2  Abc $y_2=b x$. Abc $c^2$.
     3  Abc $y_2=b x$.
     4  Abc $y_1=A x$. 
     5  abc $y_1=x$.
     6  abc abc. $E=mc^2$.
$ grep -n '\$[^\$]*A[^\$]*\$' test.tex 
1:Abc $y_1=A x$. 
2:Abc $y_2=b x$. Abc $c^2$.
4:Abc $y_1=A x$.
```

Line 2 is shown by grep, but I don't want this case to show up, because the matching A is outside the math environment delimeters. Is it possible to fix this regular expression such that the cases similar to the second match are avoided? I guess my question can be generalized to asking is it possible for the regex to be aware of its context?

If I were to think of a solution to my problem, I would suggest the following "abstract idea":

```
 B = TRUE 
 For every match that grep finds
     If B is TRUE 
        Display the match
     End if
     B = not B
 End for
```

In other words, when grep finds a match, display it only if B is TRUE, invert B, and repeat for all the matches.

This idea should work, because I don't have nested math expressions in my document. So can we implement this idea with grep? Or any better idea please?

Comment: The second part in line 2, `$. Abc $c^2$` has `A` present between `$..$`, how can you avoid that (condition)?

Comment: you can use word boundary to limit stand alone letter matches, but need to still worry about math environment that spans multiple lines, or other uses of dollar sign within the text.

Comment: You might consider replacing the raw `A` with an appropriate command, so that if you need to change the lower-case `a`s to something else again in the future, you only need to change the definition of the command in one place.

Comment: Hi @Inian: how about the "abstract" idea that I wrote in my post? Don't you think it can solve my problem, or at least conceptually? Don't you think this is implementable?

Comment: Hi @karakfa: true and valid comments, thank you.

Comment: Hi @chepner: Thanks for the idea. But it seems you don't think that this can be automated, and I should prepare myself for future change requests, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try:

```
perl -pnE 's/ (\$.*?\$) / $1 =~ s:A:a:gr /xge'
```

- it searches **pairs** or `dollar` *text* `dollar` (e.g. math expressions)
- and inside each pair change A -> a
- repeat with next pair
- the pairs are shown bellow as `mmmmm`

e.g. from

```
Abc $y_2=A A x$. A A $c^2$. Ab A $y_1=AaA x$. A $ dol
____mmmmmmmmmmm______mmmmm_______mmmmmmmmmmm_________ 
# the  m shows the matched pairs e.g. the "inside of the math expr"
```

produces

```
Abc $y_2=a a x$. A A $c^2$. Ab A $y_1=aaa x$. A $ dol
```

### EDIT2 - for multiline and honors escaped `\$`

to allow multiline need a bit different:

> <s>perl -0 -pE 's/ (\$.*?\$) / $1 =~ s:A:a:gr /xges' file.lat</s>

```
perl -0 -pE 's/ (?<!\\) (\$ .*? (?<!\\) \$) / $1 =~ s:A:a:gr /xges'
```

- the `-0` "slurps" the whole file into perl
- and added the `s` modifier
- uses negative lookbehind for the `\$`

demo from the input

```
Abc $y_1=A x$. 
Abc $y_2=b x$. Abc $c^2$. $y_1=A x$.
Abc $y_2=b x$.
Abc $y_1=A x
      still AAA inside multi line
      math AAA end->$. A-outside here
 in \$ still in AAA out \$ still out.
still A outside $ Again A AA inside
multi  up to \$ still AA inside
here $ A out
abc $y_1=x$.
abc abc. $E=mc^2$.
```

produces

```
Abc $y_1=a x$. 
Abc $y_2=b x$. Abc $c^2$. $y_1=a x$.
Abc $y_2=b x$.
Abc $y_1=a x
      still aaa inside multi line
      math aaa end->$. A-outside here
 in \$ still in AAA out \$ still out.
still A outside $ again a aa inside
multi  up to \$ still aa inside
here $ A out
abc $y_1=x$.
abc abc. $E=mc^2$.
```

Ps: sorry, my limited english doesn't allows much more detailed explanation...

Comment: Hi @jm666: Is it possible to please explain the code in your answer? I'm sorry to ask you this, but I'm not familiar with the syntax of the perl language.

Comment: Thank you @jm666 . You explained it crystal clear. Just one more question please: how to match a pair of $ across multiple lines?

Comment: @jm666: Also is it for this Perl command to ask me on every match whether to replace or not (like a prompt)?

Comment: Hi @Socowi : you mean like this `perl -0 -pnE 's/ (\$.*?\$) / $1 =~ s:A:a:gr /xge'`? I tried, but it did not match pairs across multiple lines.

Comment: no prompts...perl is an hard worker no chatter... :)

Comment: Possible problems: `\$` is treated like a `$`. `$$` math mode is not recognized.

Comment: @Socowi ++ true - im not sure how the `\$` should be handled. e.g. the `Abc \$ DAF \$` ? means that the `DAF` is inside? Therefore i ignored the escapes... <grin> :D

Comment: `\$` should be ignored / treated like a normal character. In your example DAF is outside. Another example: `$ in \$ still in $ out \$ still out`.

Comment: @Socowi thanx. Added a modified regex.